# Create dynamic refs to access element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I need to access an element in a vue app. However, there are multiple duplicate elements generated via a component. So the ref only works on the first component. How do I target a specific element of duplicate elements?

The component below gets the prop type, and it would serve as the unique name of the ref.

How do I either (a) create a variable that has the name of the props.type, or (b) reference a div that is within multiple components.

The Main.vue renders Component.vue multiple times. If the ref in the component has a fixed name, then I have found the ref works only works on the first instance rendered and no others.

The purpose of this in use is to scroll to the div clicked in one of the multiple components.

main.vue

```
<div v-for="(m, i) in array" 
 :key="i" >
  <Component
    :type="m"
  />
</div>
```

Component.vue

```
<template>
  <div :ref="type">text</div>
</template>
<script>
  import {
    onBeforeUpdate,
    reactive,
    ref,
  } from 'vue';
  props: {type: {type: String}}
  export default {
    setup() {
      const div = ref(null);

    onMounted(() => {
       div.value = props.type;
    });

return {
  div,
 };
},
};
</script>
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There are no duplicate elements in the code you posted. " (a) create a variable that has the name of the props.type, or (b) reference a div that is within multiple components" - can you explain further?

Comment: The code above is from a component that gets rendered multiple times. I need to know how to generate a dynamic ref for each time this component is rendered, based on the prop "type" that I can reference in the setup.

Comment: Please, show the way this component is used and how this "dynamic ref" is supposed to be used and/or the expected result. You discuss a thing that doesn't commonly occur or it's probably implemented in a more conventional way

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Added additional context with an effort to keep the code minimal.

Comment: I'm still not totally sure how it's supposed to work in whole, but currently it looks like XY problem. You have a list of SomeComponent instances and need to access their root DOM elements, something like that? Then it's something like `<SomeComponent ref="someComponents" :type="m">`, and you can access dom element like someComponents[0].$el. No need for a ref inside SomeComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply [Refs inside v-for](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for) use an array or function according to the documentation.
In the child component, use `defineExpose()` to bind to the required element [Component Reference](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component).

I created simple [**example**](https://play.vuejs.org/#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):

```
/* App.vue */
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Component from './Component.vue';

const divs = ref([]);

const cliskedDivText = ref('');

const click = (index) => {
  /* divs.value[index].div - is ref HTMLElement */
  cliskedDivText.value = divs.value[index].div.innerText 
}

const array = ['type_1', 'type_2'];

</script>

<template>
  <div
    v-for="(type, index) in array" 
    :key="index"
  >
    <Component
      :type="type"
      :ref="el => divs[index] = el"
    />
  </div> 
  <br>
  <div class="btns">
    <button
      v-for="(type, index) in array"
      @click="click(index)"
    >
      click {{ type }}
    </button>
  </div>
  <br>
  {{ cliskedDivText ? `Click to DIV with text ${cliskedDivText}` : '' }}
</template>
```

```
/* Component.vue */
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

defineProps({
  type: String,
})

const div = ref();
defineExpose({ div });
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="div">Component with {{ type }}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: The div that I want to target is not the component, but a div within the component. See above ":ref='type'" within the Component.vue

Comment: In my example div - is not the component, but a div within the component...

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough walk-through and education. A+